# ASP.NET MVC: Retrieving an .mp3 file and returning it to the user

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I currently have an HTML page that contains a link:

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="return getAudioFile('fileLocation');">Listen</a>
```

Clicking the "Listen" link calls this function:

```
    function getRecordingFile(fileLocation) {

    };
```

Which should ultimately call this controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetAudioFile(string fileLocation)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

I have emptied out the function and method because I have tried several different things to accomplish this:  I need to access an audio file from a local location and allow the user to listen to it/download it upon clicking the `Listen` link.

What seems to be the best way to go about this?

Comment: You could render an <audio> element and point it to the fileLocation on your server, whatever that is.

Comment: Rendering an audio control on the webpage would be nice, but after some digging around, it appears I would have to make some changes to IIS.  I would like to avoid that.  If "downloading" the file is the only option, I would be OK with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final result:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetAudioFile(string fileLocation)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[0];


        using (var fs = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        {
            var br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            long numBytes = new FileInfo(fileLocation).Length;
            buff = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
        }

        return File(buff, "audio/mpeg", "callrecording.mp3");
    }
```

On the page, the link is:

```
<a href="/Controller/GetAudioFile?fileName=@fileLocation">Listen</a>
```

Kudos to my boss for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a FileResult perhaps?

```
 [HttpPost]
 public FileResult GetAudioFile(string fileLocation)
 {
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileLocation)){

       return File(fs.ToArray(), "audio/mpeg");
    }

 }
```

Comment: I've done something similar.  All of the code executes, but nothing happens on the web page.  I was hoping for a prompt to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers don't enable [Partial Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fileresult.enablerangeprocessing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-fileresult-enablerangeprocessing) so a user can't seek.

Before proceeding, you should also ensure that an attacker can't traverse the filesystem by providing `../../file` or similar as a path

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetAudioFile(string fileLocation)
    {
        using var fs = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using var br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        long numBytes = new FileInfo(fileLocation).Length;
        var buff = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
        var fileResult = File(buff, "audio/mpeg", "callrecording.mp3");
        fileResult.EnableRangeProcessing = true;
        return fileResult;
    }
```